# byte compression in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compression, byte

I'm trying to transfer quite a lot of binary data very quickly over a local area network and the client app is a unity project. It all works but is very slow and so I'm now looking for a way to compress binary data in unity.

In the past I've used GZipStream, which is nice and easy but Unity doesn't support it.

Everything I've read so far is to do with unity 2 or 3 and I'm using unity 5.1. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is it slow because the network cannot transport that much data in a small amount of time or because of other factors? What kind of data, what kind of data format?

Comment: Yes I know. It's binary data i.e. `byte[]`. GZipStream outputs a compressed byte array 3 times smaller than the original but i cannot decompress it in Unity so I need an alternative. Most of the data is RGBA color data. 1 byte per channel with so 64 bits per pixel.

Comment: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31902

Comment: @Bart I love you. Thanks for this link. Do you think GzipStream is a good option bearing in mind my number one priority is reducing packet size?

Comment: If there is nothing you can do about your actual packet size or data you need to transfer, it's an option. How good of one is difficult to tell without knowing the details.

Comment: @Bart. I've added the asset package to my unity project but it seems to be throwing exceptions when I try to decompress byte arrays.: `public byte[] decompress(byte[] input) {
  /*
   * This is not working.
   * Unity.IO.Compression seems to not like Decompression
   */
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
   using (GZipStream decopressor = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress)) {
    decopressor.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
   }
   return ms.ToArray();
  }
 }` It seems to specifically not like decompression. Do you know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

did you try this plugin form asset store:
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/31902

It's free :)

Comment: This has been mentioned by @Bart in the comments of the question, and might be better placed as a comment.